# How to group by SDO_GEOMETRY data type

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-spatial

I have 3 columns in a table with:

- primary key `p_id` of datatype `Number`
- a `user_id` of datatype `varchar2`
- a `shape` of data type `SDO_GEOMETRY`

I want to group by `SDO_GEOMETRY` to get rid of duplicate `shapes`

However, every time I do

```
SELECT
  p_id, user_id, shape
FROM table1
GROUP BY shape
```

I get the error

```
ORA-22901: cannot compare VARRAY or LOB attributes of an object type
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right, that won't work. Here's a little walkthrough.

Table contents:

```
SQL> select id, geom from test;

ID   GEOM(SDO_GTYPE, SDO_SRID, SDO_POINT(X, Y, Z), SDO_ELEM_INFO, SDO_ORDINATES)
---- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4026 SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE(16,9176596, 46,2173069, NULL), NULL, NULL)
4027 SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE(16,9184437, 46,2219955, NULL), NULL, NULL)
4028 SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE(16,9826714, 46,2176214, NULL), NULL, NULL)
5000 SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE(16,9176596, 46,2173069, NULL), NULL, NULL)

SQL>
```

IDs 4026 and 5000 have the same geometry, so - as you said - you'd want to get rid of one of them.

Nothing of the following works:

DISTINCT:

```
SQL> select distinct id, geom from test;
select distinct id, geom from test
                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-22901: cannot compare VARRAY or LOB attributes of an object type
```

Your attempt:

```
SQL> select id, geom from test group by geom;
select id, geom from test group by geom
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
```

Certainly, ID is missing from the GROUP BY clause, so let's add it:

```
SQL> select id, geom from test group by id, geom;
select id, geom from test group by id, geom
                                       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-22901: cannot compare VARRAY or LOB attributes of an object type
```

---

So, what to do? Use self-join with `SDO_RELATE` to find "duplicates":

```
SQL> select a.id, a.geom
  2  from test a join test b
  3    on sdo_relate(a.geom, b.geom, 'mask=equal') = 'TRUE'
  4   and a.id < b.id;

ID   GEOM(SDO_GTYPE, SDO_SRID, SDO_POINT(X, Y, Z), SDO_ELEM_INFO, SDO_ORDINATES)
---- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4026 SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE(16,9176596, 46,2173069, NULL), NULL, NULL)

SQL>
```

Right; as we know, 4026 and 5000 are the same. Because of line #4 (`a.id < b.id`) 4026 is returned.

Now it is a simple task to use the above query as a subquery (or a CTE, or whatever you find appropriate) to fetch distinct data set:

```
SQL> with duplicates as
  2    (select a.id, a.geom
  3     from test a join test b
  4       on sdo_relate(a.geom, b.geom, 'mask=equal') = 'TRUE'
  5      and a.id < b.id
  6    )
  7  select t.id, t.geom
  8  from test t
  9  where not exists (select null
 10                    from duplicates d
 11                    where d.id = t.id
 12                   );

ID   GEOM(SDO_GTYPE, SDO_SRID, SDO_POINT(X, Y, Z), SDO_ELEM_INFO, SDO_ORDINATES)
---- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4027 SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE(16,9184437, 46,2219955, NULL), NULL, NULL)
4028 SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE(16,9826714, 46,2176214, NULL), NULL, NULL)
5000 SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE(16,9176596, 46,2173069, NULL), NULL, NULL)

SQL>
```

Or:

```
SQL> select t.id, t.geom
  2  from test t
  3  where t.id not in (select a.id
  4                     from test a join test b
  5                       on sdo_relate(a.geom, b.geom, 'mask=equal') = 'TRUE'
  6                      and a.id < b.id
  7                    );

ID   GEOM(SDO_GTYPE, SDO_SRID, SDO_POINT(X, Y, Z), SDO_ELEM_INFO, SDO_ORDINATES)
---- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4027 SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE(16,9184437, 46,2219955, NULL), NULL, NULL)
4028 SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE(16,9826714, 46,2176214, NULL), NULL, NULL)
5000 SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 8307, SDO_POINT_TYPE(16,9176596, 46,2173069, NULL), NULL, NULL)

SQL>
```

Comment: VERY GOOD!  One caveat: `sdo_relate` will a) require a spatial index and b) will depend on the index's `tolerance`

Comment: Thank you, @GregStef :) I presumed that spatial index already exists.

Comment: If you only deal with points then you can just extract the X and Y of each point and compare those (via DISTINCT or GROUP BY). Just make sure to use a table alias: `SELECT P.GEOM.SDO_POINT.X AS X, P.GEOM.SDO_POINT.Y AS Y FROM TEST T` as a subquery or view, then read from that table with a GROUP BY …

Comment: I don't know if these are only points, @Albert. The OP mentions "shapes" ...

Answer (score 2):

Excellent presentation by Littlefoot - +1!
In situations where your table is big, and/or you have to group by too often and/or any other reason you might want to avoid the load of spatial queries, you might want to try adding a `varchar(128)` column to your table and fill it with a 'hash' of the row's geometry:

```
CREATE FUNCTION hash_noct( ingeom in mdsys.sdo_geometry )
  RETURN varchar2 DETERMINISTIC 
is
  v_clob     CLOB;  
  type v_tbl is table of varchar2(256); 
  v_col      v_tbl;  
  oCTID      varchar2(128); 
begin

  if ingeom is not null then  
  dbms_lob.createtemporary (v_clob, TRUE);  

  SELECT t_x||t_y  BULK COLLECT  INTO v_col  
    FROM ( select distinct t_x, t_y 
             from ( select t.id, t.x t_x, t.y t_y 
                      from table(sdo_util.getvertices(INGEOM)) t  
                     order by t.y desc, t.x asc )
            order by 2 desc, 1 asc );  

    for i in 1..v_col.count  
    loop  
    dbms_lob.writeappend(v_clob, length(v_col(i)), v_col(i));  
    end loop;  
  
  -- grant execute on sys.dbms_crypto to <your_schema> ;
  oCTID:= rawtohex( sys.dbms_crypto.hash(v_clob, 3) );
  dbms_lob.freetemporary(v_clob);  
  end if;
 RETURN oCTID ;
end hash_noct;
```

Then, in a `before insert or update` trigger, just add `:NEW.<your_hash_column_name> := hash_noct(:new.<your_geom_column_name);`
Each time you insert a geom or update an existing one, the hash column will contain a string like `7F5EF344F7684DF45EB042500C8D234FD4FD4F5F` which you can use to group by, sort or whatever.
PS: The function requires no spatial index and, as is, will use the full resolution of your stored ordinates. You should bare in mind the tolerance in which you want to compare your geometries.

Comment: I was thinking of hash as well, but thought that code I posted looks *simpler*. I'm no expert in Oracle Spatial, so - great to hear another opinion!

Comment: Your approach is excellent for small-to-moderate tables and such. It presupposes user's awareness about both the nature of the data and the true goal - Oracle's spatial approach (i.e. using tolerance) sucks at that!